# (c++23 implicit move) Returning the moved local storage variable as an rvalue ref with only parenthesisses?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference, c++23

Regarding the proposal "Simpler implicit move" ([P2266R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2266r1.html)), I'm not sure if I understand this new "move-eligible" things correctly.

Please correct these points if incorrect:
[[LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/8eaTbv1E7)]

1. `std::forward` becomes optional for perfect forwarding the rvalue ref received

```cpp
template<class T>
T&& seven(T&& x) { return std::forward<T&&>(x); }
```

becomes

```cpp
template<class T>
T&& seven(T&& x) { return x; }
```

2. `std::move` become optional for rvalue ref created locally

```cpp
Widget&&
test_seven(Widget w) {
    Widget&& rr = seven(std::move(w));
    return std::move(rr);
}
```

becomes

```cpp
Widget&&
test_seven(Widget w) {
    Widget&& rr = seven(std::move(w));
    return rr;
}
```

3. `std::move` optionaly becomes `parenthesis only` for return an rvalue ref for things created locally.

```cpp
Widget&& h3(Widget t) {
  return std::move(t);
}
```

becomes

```cpp
Widget&& h3(Widget t) {
  return (t);
}
```

Note: (3) : clang trunk warns of returning a local stack address at the time I post this.

---

## Update 2021-08-02

https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/968#issuecomment-915353127

https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P1018R13.html#P2266r1

Poll outcome: ✅ consensus. However, the against votes are from implementors, and bring relevant new information. This topic needs to be re-discussed, and might fail a plenary vote.

Comment: Interesting proposal. It'd be nice if you could add the [tag:language-lawyer] tag but I'm not sure which one of the other tags it should replace.

Comment: If you have questions about the proposal, it would probably be best to email Arthur directly. He's the one who understands the most about his proposal. Alternatively, Arthur is very active on the Cpplang Slack.

Comment: I understand like you. (And indeed `h3` returns dangling pointer (as `test_seven` and some of the examples in paper)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All three of the points are correct. In all cases, the variable in question is an *implicitly movable entity* (except `seven` if instantiated with an lvalue) and thus is treated as an xvalue.

The parentheses here:

```cpp
Widget&& h3(Widget t) {
  return (t);
}
```

don't actually do anything. They would if the function returned `decltype(auto)` - since then without parentheses the function would return `Widget` (but still move `t`, not copy it).

Comment: Is that copy elision on the last point in your answer? If so, do both `Widget` and `auto` behave the same as `decltype(auto)` you mentioned?

Comment: @sandthorn There's no copy elision here. In `h3` as written, returning `Widget` and `auto` does the same thing (both return `Widget`) but `decltype(auto)` would return `Widget&&` with the parenthesized `t`.

Comment: One more thing, the clang's warning of returning local address is correct or clang needs to be fixed not to warn of this?

Comment: @sandthorn For `h3`? Definitely correct warning. That function is 100% returning a dangling reference.

Comment: However, I understand that [P2266R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2266r1.html) will allow h3 return a local scope address. h3 will be added into non-normative of [\[class.copy.elision\]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#4). The standard allows returning local addresses or I miss anyting?

Comment: @sandthorn It's an example that helps demonstrate the language rule here. But we're still returning a reference to a local variable that is immediately being destroyed, so it's still a dangling reference.

Comment: Why does `return move(x);` not warn of local address returning while `return (x);` does? [LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/dx6eKzo53)

Comment: @sandthorn I don't understand, your link shows a warning on `move(x)`

Comment: In the middle section, you have GCC in which, of course, there sure is a warning. GCC doesn't support P2266R1 at the time we are now. In the right section, clang trunk shows no warnings.